# Photoshop warping a layer while keeping it's border?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

While using the warp transform tool, is there any way to warp inside a certain boundary? I would like to warp the inside of my layer without moving the boundaries of the layer too. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can make a selection within the boundaries of your image and just warp that portion with Transform > Warp. However, you'll end up with transparent areas as shown below. Because you're warping only a portion of the image, the tool has nothing to interpolate from to fill in the blank areas.

[image]

What you might want to investigate instead are the filters under Filter > Distort. Spherize, Ripple, etc. do draw from outside the selection.